Proper Way for Laravel Indexing for ForeignKey
Well I am new to laravel and I understand about adding index will speed up the query. However, I am bit confuse with laravel migration. Here is the code
    Schema::create('affiliate_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignIdFor(Affiliate::class,'affiliate_id')->constrained('affiliates')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->foreignIdFor(User::class,'user_id')->unique()->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        $table->string('token',50);
        $table->timestamp('expired_at');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['affiliate_id','user_id','token','expired_at','created_at','updated_at']);
    });

From the code above. There is already relation between each foreignIdFor. Should I repeat using ->index()? (affiliate_id,user_id) since its already used in foreign key.
